# How to implement a fire and forget function in Dart

Tags: dart

I have the following Dart program:

```
import 'package:pedantic/pedantic.dart';

Future someFunc() async {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    print('Value of i in someFunc(): ' + i.toString());
  }
}

Future someOtherFunc() async {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    print('Value of i in someOtherFunc(): ' + i.toString());
  }
}

Future<int> main() async {
  unawaited(someFunc());
  unawaited(someOtherFunc());
  print('End of program...');

  return 0;
}
```

When I execute this, the output is:

```
Value of i in someFunc(): 0
Value of i in someFunc(): 1
Value of i in someFunc(): 2 
...
Value of i in someFunc(): 99
Value of i in someOtherFunc(): 0
Value of i in someOtherFunc(): 1
Value of i in someOtherFunc(): 2 
...
Value of i in someOtherFunc(): 99
End of program...
```

It looks like everything was executed synchronously. I was expecting something like:

```
Value of i in someFunc(): 0
Value of i in someFunc(): 1
Value of i in someOtherFunc(): 0
Value of i in someFunc(): 3
End of program...
Value of i in someOtherFunc(): 1
(etc...)
```

How do I create an asynchronous "fire and forget" function/method in Dart?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this code execute synchronously is because asynchronous methods in Dart execute as if they're synchronous *until* the first `await`, at which point execution of that method is suspended until the `await` completes. If you were performing actual asynchronous work in your methods, you'd see interleaving execution like you expect.

For example, here's some slight modifications to your code that will roughly result in the behavior you expect:

```dart
import 'package:pedantic/pedantic.dart';

Future someFunc() async {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // Future.microtask is used to schedule work on the microtask queue,
    // which forces this method to suspend execution and continue on to someOtherFunc.
    // If you were doing some actual asynchronous work, you wouldn't need this.
    await Future.microtask(() => print('Value of i in someFunc(): ' + i.toString()));
  }
}

Future someOtherFunc() async {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    await Future.microtask(() => print('Value of i in someOtherFunc(): ' + i.toString()));
  }
}

Future<int> main() async {
  unawaited(someFunc());
  unawaited(someOtherFunc());
  print('End of program...');

  return 0;
}
```

I highly recommend reading up on the [Dart event loop and microtask queue](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a), which will give you a good understanding of how asynchrony works in Dart

Comment: Thank you so much for the very informative answer! I ran your example above, it's amazing how "cleanly" the task scheduler divides processing - it always prints one value from `someFunc()`, then one value from `someOtherFunc()`. I'm reading through the "event loop and microtask queue" article you referenced. Thanks again!